# In C#, is there any way to try multiple Regexes on string to see which one matches earlier in the string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Let's say I have an arbitrary list of regexes (`IList<Regex> lst;` for example). Is there any way to find out which one matches earlier in the string?

Of course there is the straightforward solution of trying each one on the string and seeing which match has the lowest index, but this could be inefficient on long strings.

Of course I can go back and pull the strings back out of each regex (`Regex.ToString()`) and concatenate them all together (`"(regex1)|(regex2)|(regex3)"`), but I find this to be an ugly solution, especially since it does not even indicate which regex was matched.

EDIT: Basically, is there a way to combine the already-compiled regexes without string manipulation and recompilation?

Comment: @Esailija Sorry, what I meant was which one matches earlier in the string.

Comment: The second solution you have provided *does* in fact tell you which one matched, because you can see which capturing group contains the string value.

Comment: @Asad Wouldn't you have to loop through all the groups until you find the non-empty one? That just makes the ugly solution even uglier! Although I will admit that it would work, and fairly efficiently.

Comment: You could name the groups so you only loop through the main regex groups, not any internal groups in the regex1, regex2, etc. just have to be careful with name collisions, but there is no way around it: the minimal complexity is O(number of regexes)

Comment: @EliAlgranti What's the complexity of Regex compilation? Since I would have to compile the newly assembled regex.

Comment: @Matt hmm, don't remember the complexity of building the automaton, (linear with the number of symbols in the regex?) In any case it should not be much greater than that of compiling the n regexes by themselves. So the question is whether the n regexes have already been compiled. If so running all of them on the string should be more efficient.

Comment: @EliAlgranti Running all of them on the string could be inefficient for a long string since it might have to run through the whole string for many of the Regexes even if one of them matches near the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty well known that executing one expression with multiple groups is usually slower than executing each expression in turn. It might look like creating one expression would be faster, but actually the Regex Engine will first search the whole string to find the first expression, maybe going all the way to the end of the string, but when it finds a match it will return. So there is no way to force it to return the first Match. This is due to the way the .NET Regex engine works.

Since each regex might start earlier in the string, but can potentially result in a longer match, you can't limit the end of your search to the index of the currently earliest match like this:

```
        // WARNING WILL NOT ALWAYS RESULT IN THE RIGHT VALUES
        List<Regex> rxs = new List<Regex>(4);
        rxs.Add(new Regex("def"));
        rxs.Add(new Regex("abc"));
        rxs.Add(new Regex("bcd"));
        rxs.Add(new Regex("cde"));

        string target = "abcdef";
        int firstIndex = target.Length;
        string firstMatch = string.Empty;

        foreach (var rx in rxs)
        {
            var match = rx.Match(target, 0, firstIndex);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                firstIndex = match.Index;
                firstMatch = match.Value;
                if (firstIndex == 0) break;
            }
        }
        return firstMatch;
```

This will work when you know the maximum length each regex will match, in that case use:

```
        // WARNING WILL NOT ALWAYS RESULT IN THE RIGHT VALUES
        List<Regex> rxs = new List<Regex>(4);
        rxs.Add(new Regex("def"));
        rxs.Add(new Regex("abc"));
        rxs.Add(new Regex("bcd"));
        rxs.Add(new Regex("cde"));

        string target = "abcdef";
        int firstIndex = target.Length;
        string firstMatch = string.Empty;

        foreach (var rx in rxs)
        {
            var match = rx.Match(target, 0, firstIndex + GetMaxLength(rx));
            if (match.Success)
            {
                firstIndex = match.Index;
                firstMatch = match.Value;
                if (firstIndex == 0) break;
            }
        }
        return firstMatch;
```

But you can shortcircuit as soon as you find a match on the first position, saving you any potential executions after that.

```
        foreach (var rx in rxs)
        {
            var match = rx.Match(target);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                if (match.Index < firstIndex)
                {
                    firstIndex = match.Index;
                    firstMatch = match.Value;    
                }
                if (firstIndex == 0) break;
            }
        }
```

With a little trickery you can use the index of your current first match candidate to limit the search, but I suspect it will actually still be slower than searching all possible matches:

```
        List<string> rxs = new List<string>(4);
        rxs.Add( "def");
        rxs.Add( "abc");
        rxs.Add( "bcd");
        rxs.Add( "cde");

        string target = "abcdef";
        int firstIndex = target.Length;
        string firstMatch = string.Empty;

        foreach (var rx in rxs)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(target, @"(?<!\A[\w\W]{" + firstIndex + "})" + rx);
            if (match.Success)
            {
                if (match.Index < firstIndex)
                {
                    firstIndex = match.Index;
                    firstMatch = match.Value;    
                }
                if (firstIndex == 0) break;
            }
        }
```

In the end, experiment and measure to find the way that works best for you.

---

> > I do have some extra information: At least one of the Regexes will be found near the beginning of the string.

In that case you can opt to first scan using a reasonable value for the length index, so use `rx.Match(targetstring, 0, 1024 /* First scan */)` and only if you don't find a match, widen your search in a second pass. If your target string can be really large this will save a lot of compute power.

Comment: So basically you're saying that .NET does not have a very good implementation of Regexes. How unfortunate...

Comment: It does have a good implementation of Regex, but not for your problem at hand. There are two types of Regex engines, DFA and NFA [1], they have different characteristics. .NET is based on NFA which will result in finding a match, but won't tell you whether it is the smallest, first, last match etc. The DFA algorithm results in the smallest match or the first match, depending on the implementation, but comes with a lot of limitations. 

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: I will take that as a compliment ;). You were totally correct, but somehow not connecting to the original poster. In some parts you seem to have your deep NFA/DFA knowledge a lot more actual than me :). I tried a different approach with a lot of examples. Seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `RegularExpressions.Match` type returned by regular expressions matching contains an `Index` property which indicates the position in the original string where the match was found.

You can compare this from the several different regular expression results to determine the one that is the first match.

Something like

```
 (from m in regexList
 let match = m.Match(targetstring)
 orderby match.Index
 select m.Value).FirstOrDefault()
```

Note:  I haven't tested this for syntax or other issues, since you didn't provide any code to cut and paste into Linqpad quickly to create a test environment, and I have to go to work right now.  But this should give you the general idea.

And this has nothing to do with whether the regex's are already compiled or not--eventually you are going to have to try each of them against the target string.

Since the runtime environment manages the compilation and caching of your compiled regular expressions in normal circumstances, I am not sure what your question is getting at, unless there is additional information or context not yet shared that would permit a regex to be selected prior to trying it against the target string.

Comment: Like I said in the question, this is inefficient for long strings because it might have to search through the entire string multiple times before it eventually gets to a Regex that it finds at the very beginning.

Comment: And yet it is mathmatically equivilent to combining the regexes into a single master regex.   Either way, the same amount of string processing will occur.  Mark me down all you want, but you cannot reduce the fundamental complexity of the problem unless you restructure the problem.  Unless there is additional information or context that would allow you to build a BETTER master regex than the concatenation of the regexes in the list, the answer I have given you is as good as it gets.

Comment: I do have some extra information: At least one of the Regexes will be found near the beginning of the string.

Comment: Then you can use a heuristic, with either method, of only checking the first n characters of the target string, and failing back to checking the full string, but that doesn't change the complexity of the regex searching.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that wouldn't involve your own regex matcher would indeed be the concatenation route. You can put each one in a named subgroup and afterwards look which group actually matched to figure out which original regex matched.

I wonder why you're so worried about recompilation as that step is likely not the bottleneck if you're simultaneously worried about large inputs ...

Comment: But it will still have to search for the results of every regex subexpression, and so will be of equivilent algorithmic complexity.

Comment: I guess a regex engine could do smarter for alternatives than try each one on the whole input.

Comment: It cannot, because it wouldn't know if a later alternative occurred earlier in the string than the prior sub expressions.  It still has to exhaustively search.

Comment: The graph can have multiple end states and thus match several paths (alternatives) at once.

Comment: Not in this case, and NDFAs (which have to be converted to DFAs to execute internally) don't work that way.  While in theory they can traverse multiple edges at once, in an actual digitial computer, that has to be simulated in series.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ The point is that once a match is found, the rest of the string is not searched.

Comment: @Matt That would assume that the internal implementation of the regex scanning engine in a case like `r1|r2|r3|...` scans the sub-elements `r` partially in parallel, rather than completely scanning `r1` then scanning `r2` and so on.   Most implementations methodologies I have seen do the latter, not the former--but even if they did do the former, that would be depending on an implementation detail. The only possible true optimization to this problem is to use outside information that we do not currently have for a better heurstic, or to write a custom DFA.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I think you might be confusing the length of the match with the index of the first character of the match. I am look for the lowest of the latter, not of the former.

Comment: @matt I am not confusing them.   If you have more information than you have shared, we can help you do a better heuristic.  For example, if you know the maximum match length is `n` and it is likely to occur in the first `m` characters of the target string, a heuristic with a probably improved outcome would be possible by not searching the entire target string on the first pass.  Otherwise the DFA  implemented by the regex engine WILL do an exhaustive search.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Where are you getting your information about how the C# implementation works?

Comment: I am not assuming ANYTHING about how the implementation works.  I am saying it would have to work a certain way to get your desired result, and I have never seen in my compsci books or other research on these things an implementation plan that works like that.  You can always run implementation dependent practical tests.  You can compile the regex to an assembly, and inspect the assembly.  But I cannot give you magic.  You could share more information on your use case so we could help you with the practical aspect, and not theory.    But there is no magic here.